# Multiple API Fetch - Error: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I am working with the News Data API and the array that comes back from the API is an array called articles.

[image: articles data array]

I am trying to convert these two function calls to use the `.then` approach.

```
export async function getNews() {
  try {
    let articles = await fetch(`${articles_url}?q=${category}${date}`, {
      headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': api_key,
      },
    });

    let result = await articles.json();
    return result.articles;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
export async function getTrending() {
  try {
    let articles = await fetch(`${articles_url_trending}?q=${blockchain}`, {
      headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': api_key,
      },
    });

    let result = await articles.json();
    return result.articles;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I have two empty arrays: `articles` and `trending`.

I am trying to do two separate fetch calls and load each array respectively.

The fetch seems to be working fine but I am receiving two errors:

1. > Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN
2. > TaskQueue: Error with task: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {articles: [], refreshing: true, trending: []};
    this.fetchNews = this.fetchNews.bind(this);
  }
  // Called after a component is mounted
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchNews();
  }

  fetchNews() {
    Promise.all([
      fetch(
        'url1',
      ),
      fetch(
        'url2',
      ),
    ])
      .then(([articles, trending]) => {
        return Promise.all([articles.json(), trending.json()]);
      })
      .then(([articles, trending]) => {
        this.setState({articles: articles, trending: trending});
      });
  }

  handleRefresh() {
    this.setState(
      {
        refreshing: true,
      },
      () => this.fetchNews(),
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-inline-styles
          style={styles.bgColor}
          data={this.state.articles}
          renderItem={({item}) => <DataItem article={item} />}
          keyExtractor={item => item.url}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
          ListHeaderComponent={() => (
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.text}> Trending </Text>
              <Carousel
                layout={'default'}
                data={this.state.trending}
                renderItem={({item}) => <CarouselItem article={item} />}
                sliderWidth={SLIDER_WIDTH}
                itemWidth={300}
              />
              <Text style={styles.text}> Blockchain News </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: on which line do you get the error?

Comment: @TobiasS. trying to figure that out myself, seems to be an issue with the index of the arrays? I also updated my errors.

Comment: I think you should try calling other api inside .then of first api. Also try using Interaction Manager inside ComponentDidMount

Comment: @VishalRabadiya hm, i am not understanding, I do call the fetch api, and follow with .then